# Can I run an SQL-query in an iFrame by using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, mysql, iframe

I have 2 iFrames containing grids (phpGrid) with some stuff from a database.
I want it to do this: when I click on a row in the left iFrame I want it to load a new SQL-query in the right iFrame. So it's allways up-to-date.

The left iFrame has classes in a (sort of) drag race. In the right I want it to load the name, hometown and the car of which the racers are driving.

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: I haven't thought about that. But I have never used AJAX before. But I'll see if this is possible.

Comment: AJAX should be the ONLY way IMO since the whole iFrame approach feels kind of unflexible and may result in an less elegant UI.